# Couldn't detect device's shakes

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, accelerometer, shake, first-responder

I'm trying to detect when the device(iPhone/iPod Touch) shakes, what I have already done (in my viewController.m) is :

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder{
return YES;
}
```

.

```
- (void) motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake){
NSLog(@"Motion detected");
}
}
```

and I've added this line to viewDidLoad :

```
BOOL ret = [self becomeFirstResponder];
```

Then, I build&ran the app, and tried to shake the device but nothing happened!.. I started troubleshooting the problem, by using Breakpoints, what I detected is that the "ret" value returned from [self becomeFirstResponder] is "NO". 
And couldn't know what is the problem. Any help ?

```
Info : using Xcode 4, and iOS 4.3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution..

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

should be only implemented in viewDidAppear: because I tried it in viewWillAppear: and viewDidLoad and it's not working in the both methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Shaking-Motion Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW2)?

Comment: Yeah, and that's what I really did. But still the same problem :(